# Overflow for div with 100% height inside of table row

Tags: css

I'd like to create a table with one row that wraps its content, and a second row that that takes up the rest of the space. If the second row's content overflows, I'd like it to scroll. I can achieve these effects on chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/a0g8bcu0/

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#row {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="container">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>This is a little bit of text</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row">
    <td id="cell">
      <div id="sidebar">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, this doesn't work on Firefox. Can anyone give me some insight? I realize that height scaling in tables can be a bit strange. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this:

```css
#cell {
    height: 0;
}
```

This reduces the height of the cell as much as possible –making `#sidebar` overflow–, but since `#row` still has `height: 100%`, it will cover the remaining space of the table.

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#row {
  height: 100%;
}
#cell {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="container">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>This is a little bit of text</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row">
    <td id="cell">
      <div id="sidebar">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ooh, this is actually better solution.  Very clever!

Answer (score 1):

It's not purely CSS, but it works on every browser:  http://jsfiddle.net/a0g8bcu0/2/

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#sidebar').height($('#sidebar').parent().height());
} );
```

Comment: Thanks. This works too, but I appreciate the pure CSS below because it adapts to changes in the parent container's size.

Comment: I agree.  Oriol's solution is much more elegant than mine.