# Vertical scroll on vertically centered div with dynamic height

Tags: html, css

I use `display:table` and `vertical-align:middle` to vertically center a div with dynamic height.

CSS

```
.table {
  display:table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Useless */
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="content">
            Then this text becomes too long, it will cause
            the .table div to expand beyond its container
            even if set to height: 100%
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the `content` div to get a vertical scroll when its height becomes greater than the `table` div (or rather the `table` div's parent)?

[JS Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/0q78gbvh)

Comment: Related: [Overflow for div with 100% hieght inside of table row](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27026098/1529630)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a CSS tables approach, you can use the [Centering in the unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) approach:

```css
.cell, .cell:before {
  height: 100%;
}
.cell:before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
.cell:before, .cont {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cont {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```css
.margin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  top: 32px;
  bottom: 32px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
.cell, .cell:before {
  height: 100%;
}
.cell:before {
  content: '';
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
.cell:before, .cont {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cont {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="cont">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla cursus lacinia ipsum quis pharetra. Donec vitae quam placerat lectus lobortis congue. Suspendisse maximus euismod aliquam. Ut sagittis risus vitae mauris imperdiet, ac venenatis orci dignissim. Nam felis dui, commodo non venenatis in, pulvinar a lectus. Duis lacus nulla, fringilla ut malesuada vel, iaculis ut dui. Nunc venenatis imperdiet tortor, eu sollicitudin velit vulputate finibus. In placerat justo lacus, quis faucibus leo varius ornare. Mauris vestibulum ligula in est pellentesque commodo. Donec sollicitudin dui quis quam pretium, eget sollicitudin risus pellentesque. Duis eget lacus varius, finibus augue ac, auctor eros. Proin vestibulum mauris vitae urna volutpat, non ultrices felis ultricies.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Only 1 little problem could be that when you are on a small screen, the .cell displays under its parent. Little fix for that using a media query: http://jsfiddle.net/0q78gbvh/9/ . Now, it only displays under its parent when the screen is VERY small

Comment: @JoJo True, thanks. It can be fixed in different ways, like [`box-sizing: border-box; max-width: 100%;`](http://jsfiddle.net/0q78gbvh/10/) or [using `white-space` to prevent wrapping](http://jsfiddle.net/0q78gbvh/11/)

Comment: That is a clever solution without having to resolve to stuff like `display:flex`. I'll stick to this one. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `.row` element:

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="content">Long text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  height: /* something */;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 0;
}
.cont {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This reduces the height of `.cell` as much as possible –making `.cont` overflow–, but since `.row` has `height: 100%`, it will cover `.table`.

```css
.margin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 32px;
  right: 32px;
  top: 32px;
  bottom: 32px;
  background: yellow;
}
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 0;
}
.cont {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        <div class="cont">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla cursus lacinia ipsum quis pharetra. Donec vitae quam placerat lectus lobortis congue. Suspendisse maximus euismod aliquam. Ut sagittis risus vitae mauris imperdiet, ac venenatis
            orci dignissim. Nam felis dui, commodo non venenatis in, pulvinar a lectus. Duis lacus nulla, fringilla ut malesuada vel, iaculis ut dui. Nunc venenatis imperdiet tortor, eu sollicitudin velit vulputate finibus. In placerat justo lacus, quis
            faucibus leo varius ornare. Mauris vestibulum ligula in est pellentesque commodo. Donec sollicitudin dui quis quam pretium, eget sollicitudin risus pellentesque. Duis eget lacus varius, finibus augue ac, auctor eros. Proin vestibulum mauris
            vitae urna volutpat, non ultrices felis ultricies.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer seems to work in both Chrome (v39) and Firefox (v37), but not in IE 11; which is best so far :) . I will fiddle a bit with the added row and see if I can get it work on all three.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the .table div that expands beyond its container. It's the .cont div.

```
.cont {
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    background: #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Nothing in this class limits the height to 100%, so the .cont div will expand beyond the borders of .table

Just add `max-heigh:100%` to limit it to 100% of the parent's (.cell) height. And then the `overflow:auto` (that was already there) should do the rest of the job

http://jsfiddle.net/0q78gbvh/1/

**EDIT:** This will not work in all browsers, because you can't set the max-height from display:table directly in those browsers.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Chrome either, in which case the `max-height` on the content div causes it to collapse for some strange reason.

Comment: @JoJo Ah, then it might be because of me using v34 for Linux. I will try it in Windows.

Comment: @Jojo True, it works fine on Chrome v39. But not in Firefox v36 or IE11. Hmm, seems I should consider a completely different approach.

Comment: @ANisus I'll check too ;)

Comment: @ANisus it's because of the display:table and display:table-cell . It's not possible to set their max-height

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to achieve the same effect is to use `display: flex` instead of `display: table`

```css
.flex {
    position:absolute;
    left:32px; right:32px; top:32px; bottom:32px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background:yellow;
}
.item {
    max-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 264px;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    background: #ddd;
 border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="item">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla cursus lacinia ipsum quis pharetra. Donec vitae quam placerat lectus lobortis congue. Suspendisse maximus euismod aliquam. Ut sagittis risus vitae mauris imperdiet, ac venenatis orci dignissim. Nam felis dui, commodo non venenatis in, pulvinar a lectus. Duis lacus nulla, fringilla ut malesuada vel, iaculis ut dui. Nunc venenatis imperdiet tortor, eu sollicitudin velit vulputate finibus. In placerat justo lacus, quis faucibus leo varius ornare. Mauris vestibulum ligula in est pellentesque commodo. Donec sollicitudin dui quis quam pretium, eget sollicitudin risus pellentesque. Duis eget lacus varius, finibus augue ac, auctor eros. Proin vestibulum mauris vitae urna volutpat, non ultrices felis ultricies.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works in Chrome (v39), Firefox (v36), and IE11. However, IE11 doesn't seem to regrow the `item` div once the scrollbar has been added, even if there is space for it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Since you have a `<p>` element in ur jsFiddle Eg, set a max height to the container equal to the *.margin*

```
.cont {
width: 240px;
padding: 0px 12px;
background: #ddd;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
border: 1px solid #000;
max-height:300px; /* Fixed max-height of container... */
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/brahmadathsm/ns3dmhwy/)

Comment: In case of a fixed height container, this works. Unfortunately that is not my case. But thanks for the suggestion!